# Cannot find name 'Symbol' when compiling typescript

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm receiving the following error when trying to compile a ts file:

`node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(121,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.`

I did some reading and saw that this can be linked to not having the correct target or lib options declared in the `tsconfig.json` file.  I've tried a few different things such as changing the target to "es15" and including "es2015" in the lib, but I am not having much luck.

I am using this tutorial as a basis for my project:
https://itnext.io/building-restful-web-apis-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-typescript-part-1-2-195bdaf129cf

File structure:

```
dist
lib
├──controllers
|  ├──controller.ts
|
├──models
|  ├──model.ts
|
├──routes
|  ├──routes.ts
|
├──app.ts
├──server.ts
node_modules
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2017",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noImplicitThis": false,
      "removeComments": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "pretty": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "noLib": false,
      "jsx": "react",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "lib": ["es2017"],
      "baseUrl": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
      "lib/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

model.ts:

```
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const filepath = __dirname + '/../file.txt'

function asyncReadFile(filepath: string, type: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filepath, (err, data) => {
      console.log("Reading file...")
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)
    })
  })
}

asyncReadFile(filepath, 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Does the problem still occur with `"lib": ["ESNext"]`?

Comment: have had the same problem with "esnext", I've added "es2015" and it works like a charme.

Comment: Hello, Did you get solution for this? I am facing the same problem. The version of @types\node is 6.9.0

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for es2017 will it work or not but

I was using

```
"target":"es5"
```

and lib was initially in tsconfig.ts

```
"lib":[]
```

and still getting error.

I found solution at this github [post](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25793) and it worked. In summary,

edit your tsconfig.ts file with

```
 "lib": [
  "es2015"
]
```

my node version : 8.11.2 and npm version : 5.6.0 , just if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not including all required libraries for es7 target. 
If you downgrade your target to es5 and remove libs option, you should be good.